# Delete a Signed URL manually with PHP (Google Cloud)

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, signed-url

I was wonder if there is a way to manually destroy a signed URL from the PHP library of Google Cloud or some parameter to specify inside the generation to say "when link is open the first time, destroy it".

At this moment I've found only a "time" to set from the generation of Signed URL, nothing else.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

> Is there is a way to manually destroy a signed URL?

You would need to delete the service account **key** which could have a several minute delay and would also invalidate other signed URLs.

Validation of signed URLs is via the public key and timestamp. If the timestamp has not expired, all that is left is to delete the public key which requires deleting the service account's private key.

In the event that the Signed URL was generated by the Google Managed service account key, then you must delete the service account.

Comment: Clear, so the best way is to set the timestamp to few seconds from when the signed URL is generated and let the signed URL invalidate after that period.

Comment: @tidpe - set the timestamp to be as long as required and no longer. Your question does not indicate how the signed URL is used. If used by a robot (software), you can probably estimate the time until the link is used. If by a human, how will you know? I use a trick on my websites. I pass a URL on my server to the client. When they click the link it goes to my backend which then creates the signed URL and 307 redirects the client. This ensures that Signed URLs do not need to exist for long periods of time.

Comment: Thank you, this is the way how I'm creating that: it's supposed to be used from users, when user need it, I just create it and serve content to user.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is to **rename the object**. after renaming, all old signed-urls will not work anymore and the service account is still intact.
(see my full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73209023/16550663)

About generating one-time url, I think it's nearly impossible especially for google cloud storage. The only solution I came up with is to use [streaming upload/download](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#stream_an_upload). with this technique, your api server acts as a forwarding server and can easily control how many times the client can request. but be alert of cost of Network Ingress/Egress when streaming large file.